# Predicting lux values from images?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

I have several images (frames from a camera approx. 25,000 images) for which I have one unique lux value ranging from 1 to 110,000). Not all the lux values are covered from 1 to 110,000. Now, I need to predict the lux values in real-time for the same camera once every second, especially predicting the low lux values (1 to 6) are of prime importance.

How do I do it?

I have found one link where there's piecewise relation shown between lighting step (don't understand what the author means by that) and mean lux values [here in the second graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SensorsAPI/understanding-and-interpreting-lux-values).

Should I do plain linear regression on these sparse values? If yes, how does that work? Any guide or link will be helpful. Or string together a piecewise linear set of equations to predict the lux values from mean intensities of my frames?

Comment: This question seems out of scope; you'd be better off doing independent research on intensity (digital count) to lux (radiometric quantity). It's certainly possible, but depends on camera parameters and operation. If you can narrow the focus you may get a better answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data are reliable (low noise), use a smooth interpolation method. I would recommend cubic splines. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicSpline.html.

Computation of the coefficients is not too clostly (O(N) for N points). To interpolate were you need to, there are two situations:

- sequential values: scan the intervals incrementally,
- random values: use dichotomic search to find the relevant interval.

As your range seems to be large, I would recommend a bilogarithmic transformation before interpolation

```
Y = log(f(e^X))
```

---

**Addendum:**

There is no reason for the relation between the steps and the lux value to be complicated. On the opposite, you would expect a monotonous function, with monotonous derivatives. For this case, fitting of a simple nonlinear model might be more appropriate (say exponential or low-degree polynomial), and better than sticking to the available data.